# Angular - On resize want to redirect to other page

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using Angular 4 and went for window.onresize for triggering event on resize. I wrote that in constructor after I loaded doctors component, that is not triggering. The thing is I am showing doctors component as side panel on clicking doctors hyperlink.

I am using sneakPeak variable for showing and hiding side panel.

```
constructor(private router: Router) {
    window.onresize = (e) =>
    {
        this.width = window.innerWidth;
        if(this.width <= 1000 && this.sneakPeak) {
            this.router.navigate(['/doctors']);
        }
   };
}
```

I wanna redirect to doctors page, if I resize window below 1000px(width). How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should use `HostListener` from `@angular/core` for subscribing to events of the DOM element.

```
@HostListener('window:resize', ['$event'])
onResize(event) {
  if(event.target.innerWidth <= 1000 && this.sneakPeak) {
    this.router.navigate(['/doctors']);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend registering the event in the template. This probably would cause problems in `server side render` because of the `window` reference.

```
//our root app component
import { Component, NgModule, VERSION} from '@angular/core'
import { BrowserModule} from '@angular/platform-browser'

@Component({
  selector: 'my-app',
  template: `<div (window:resize)="onResize($event)">hello</div>`,

})
export class AppComponent {
  onResize(event) {
   const innerWidth = event.target.innerWidth;
   console.log(innerWidth);
  }
}
```

I try to share a plunker here: http://plnkr.co/edit/CSZKfH?p=preview